# Merging rows based on a condition in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
library(tibble)


data <- tibble(
  SheetID = c("Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet1"),
  ID = c(170, 170, 199, 199, 239, 239, 268, 485, 485, 485, 485, 485, 485),
  ID.2 = c(36, 36, 86, 86, 66, 66, 72, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34),
  description = c("pain", "", "skin", "", "Not provided", "", "done", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
  Code = c(395, 398, 395, 398, 395, 398, 381, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326),
  Test = c("SCREEN", "INDEX", "SCREEN", "INDEX", "SCREEN", "INDEX", "DDA", "Sy", "RaP", "SS-DJA", "RAT", "SSMU", "SLI20"),
  value = c("ND", 0.4, "ND", 0.2, "ND", 0, "<7", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"),
  Date = c("15/11/2020", "16/11/2020", "17/11/2020", "18/11/2020", "19/11/2020", "20/11/2020", "21/11/2020", "22/11/2020", "23/11/2020", "24/11/2020", "25/11/2020", "26/11/2020", "27/11/2020"),
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M")
)
```

I want to modify the data in a way that merge the test values( only screen and index) to be in one row and keep the rest of the data as it. so the output should be like this:

```
SheetID  ID ID.2  description Code          Test   value       Date group
1   Sheet1 170   36         pain  395 SCREEN, INDEX ND, 0.4 15/11/2020      F
2   Sheet1 199   86         skin  395 SCREEN, INDEX ND, 0.2 17/11/2020      F
3   Sheet1 239   66 Not provided  395 SCREEN, INDEX   ND, 0 19/11/2020      F
4   Sheet1 268   72     diabetic  381           DDA      <7 21/11/2020      F
5   Sheet1 485   34               321            Sy       N 22/11/2020      M
6   Sheet1 485   34               322           RaP       N 23/11/2020      M
7   Sheet1 485   34               323        SS-DJA       N 24/11/2020      M
8   Sheet1 485   34               324           RAT       N 25/11/2020      M
9   Sheet1 485   34               325          SSMU       N 26/11/2020      M
10  Sheet1 485   34               326         SLI20       N 27/11/2020      M
```

Basically I want to gather the test and the value columns if they have the same ID, ID.2 if they are equal to Index and screen. Can you please help?
Thank you

Comment: What if an ID has SCREEN, INDEX, and SCREEN, still one line?

Comment: Hi There is no such situation in the data , so its always with screen there is index.  the rows with  screen should have the index value in the same line of the value column .Thank you for asking

Comment: What happens to the `code, value, date` columns? How do you combine them?

Comment: `gender` ? where's that from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on assumption that we can also split the dataset by `Test` (*SCREEN*, *INDEX*, others) and final `description`, `Code`, `Date` & `group` values are defined by *SCREEN* subset.

Once dataset is split, we can join *SCREEN* & *INDEX* subsets by `ID, ID.2`, unite columns and bind back together with the rest:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

test_split <- split(data, fct_other(data$Test, keep = c("SCREEN", "INDEX")))

left_join(test_split$SCREEN, 
          select(test_split$INDEX, ID, ID.2, Test, value), 
          by = join_by(ID, ID.2)) %>% 
  mutate(Test  = paste(Test.x, Test.y, sep = ", "),
         value = paste(value.x, value.y, sep = ", "), 
         .keep = "unused", .after = "Code") %>% 
  bind_rows(test_split$Other)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 9
#>    SheetID    ID  ID.2 description     Code Test          value   Date     group
#>    <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>         <chr>   <chr>    <chr>
#>  1 Sheet1    170    36 "pain"           395 SCREEN, INDEX ND, 0.4 15/11/2… A    
#>  2 Sheet1    199    86 "skin"           395 SCREEN, INDEX ND, 0.2 17/11/2… A    
#>  3 Sheet1    239    66 "Not provided"   395 SCREEN, INDEX ND, 0   19/11/2… A    
#>  4 Sheet1    268    72 "done"           381 DDA           <7      21/11/2… A    
#>  5 Sheet1    485    34 ""               321 Sy            N       22/11/2… M    
#>  6 Sheet1    485    34 ""               322 RaP           N       23/11/2… M    
#>  7 Sheet1    485    34 ""               323 SS-DJA        N       24/11/2… M    
#>  8 Sheet1    485    34 ""               324 RAT           N       25/11/2… M    
#>  9 Sheet1    485    34 ""               325 SSMU          N       26/11/2… M    
#> 10 Sheet1    485    34 ""               326 SLI20         N       27/11/2… M
```

`test_split` :

```
#> $INDEX
#> # A tibble: 3 × 9
#>   SheetID    ID  ID.2 description  Code Test  value Date       group
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#> 1 Sheet1    170    36 ""            398 INDEX 0.4   16/11/2020 A    
#> 2 Sheet1    199    86 ""            398 INDEX 0.2   18/11/2020 A    
#> 3 Sheet1    239    66 ""            398 INDEX 0     20/11/2020 A    
#> 
#> $SCREEN
#> # A tibble: 3 × 9
#>   SheetID    ID  ID.2 description   Code Test   value Date       group
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#> 1 Sheet1    170    36 pain           395 SCREEN ND    15/11/2020 A    
#> 2 Sheet1    199    86 skin           395 SCREEN ND    17/11/2020 A    
#> 3 Sheet1    239    66 Not provided   395 SCREEN ND    19/11/2020 A    
#> 
#> $Other
#> # A tibble: 7 × 9
#>   SheetID    ID  ID.2 description  Code Test   value Date       group
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#> 1 Sheet1    268    72 "done"        381 DDA    <7    21/11/2020 A    
#> 2 Sheet1    485    34 ""            321 Sy     N     22/11/2020 M    
#> 3 Sheet1    485    34 ""            322 RaP    N     23/11/2020 M    
#> 4 Sheet1    485    34 ""            323 SS-DJA N     24/11/2020 M    
#> 5 Sheet1    485    34 ""            324 RAT    N     25/11/2020 M    
#> 6 Sheet1    485    34 ""            325 SSMU   N     26/11/2020 M    
#> 7 Sheet1    485    34 ""            326 SLI20  N     27/11/2020 M
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ margusl  Thank you so much I really appreciate your help God bless you.